# aws.s3: get version information for S3 file

Tags: r, amazon-s3

Using aws.s3 package for R, I would like to get a list of the versions of an object. This has already been asked as a github issue https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.s3/issues/277, but with no response.
Something like

```
get_versions(bucket="mybucket", path="myfilepath")
```

or

```
get_versions(bucket="mybucket", prefix="myprefix")
```

but these in fact return the entire contents, same as

```
get_versions(bucket="mybucket")
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't technically answer the question, but you can do it easily with the [paws package](https://github.com/paws-r/paws/). You can just do

```
s3$get_object("bucket",Key=key,VersionId = vid)
```